# Load JNI Ubuntu Fails

Tags: java, c, gcc, java-native-interface

I am trying to load the JNI library and run the below program but I am getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JNIDemo      
in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at demo.JNIWrapper.<clinit>(JNIWrapper.java:10)
```

Below are my Java,C,command

Step1:Java Code :Present in a Eclipse Project at Path (/documents/JNIDemoProject/src/main/java/demo)

```
package demo;

public class JNIWrapper {

static{


    //System.load("/home/arpit/Documents/JNI/libJNIDemo.so");

    System.loadLibrary("JNIDemo");
}


public native int multiply(int a,int b);


public static void main(String args[]){

    try{

    JNIWrapper jni=new JNIWrapper();
    int result=jni.multiply(7, 8);
    System.out.println("Result is "+result);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Step 2:A .h file named demo_JNIWrapper was created (Note name is demo_JNIWrapper as I had to run the javah command from /documents/JNIDemoProject/src/main/java)

```
 /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class demo_JNIWrapper */

#ifndef _Included_demo_JNIWrapper
#define _Included_demo_JNIWrapper
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     demo_JNIWrapper
 * Method:    multiply
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_multiply
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif
```

Step 3:
I create a C file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "demo_JNIWrapper.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_multiply
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jint a, jint b){

int result=a*b;
return result;
}
```

Step 4:
I create the lib file named libJNIDemo.so

Step 5:
All the three files(libJNIDemo.so,demo_JNIWrapper.h,HelloJNI.c) are located at the folder /users/documents/JNI

Step 6:
I export it into lib path 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/users/documents/JNI"`

Step7:
When I run the java program it gives me the above error .

POINT TO NOTE:
My program runs fine when I load the libJniDemo.so file directly with the path

```
static{


    System.load("/users/documents/JNI/libJNIDemo.so");

    //System.loadLibrary("JNIDemo");
}
```

Can anyone please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Java uses `dlopen()` on Linux (and other Unix or Unix-like operating systems) to find native libraries.  From the Linux `dlopen()` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

```
   If filename is NULL, then the returned handle is for the main
   program.  If filename contains a slash ("/"), then it is interpreted
   as a (relative or absolute) pathname.  Otherwise, the dynamic linker
   searches for the object as follows (see ld.so(8) for further
   details):

   o   (ELF only) If the executable file for the calling program
       contains a DT_RPATH tag, and does not contain a DT_RUNPATH tag,
       then the directories listed in the DT_RPATH tag are searched.

   o   If, at the time that the program was started, the environment
       variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was defined to contain a colon-separated
       list of directories, then these are searched.  (As a security
       measure, this variable is ignored for set-user-ID and set-group-
       ID programs.)

   o   (ELF only) If the executable file for the calling program
       contains a DT_RUNPATH tag, then the directories listed in that
       tag are searched.

   o   The cache file /etc/ld.so.cache (maintained by ldconfig(8)) is
       checked to see whether it contains an entry for filename.

   o   The directories /lib and /usr/lib are searched (in that order).
```

If you can, run your Java process under `strace`, trace `open` calls, and see where the JVM is looking for your native library, and exactly what it's looking for.

Given knowing how `dlopen()` work, and the information from `strace`, you should be able to determine exactly what's happening.

One thing to be aware of:  you may be creating a 64-bit native library but running a 32-bit JVM.

Comment: I am running 64-bit JVM and have export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/users/documents/JNI" which contains the .so file

Comment: So what's the `strace` output from tracing `open()` calls tell you?